# How to make clangd use diagnostics flags?

Tags: neovim, language-server-protocol, clangd

I'm trying to setup `clangd` with Neovim built-in LSP Config and it is working fine. Problem is, usually I compile everything with the flags `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`, how can I make `clangd` use these flags when analyzing code and prompt for errors?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clangd` accepts global configuration via `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/clangd/config.yaml`. You can add Compile Flags with:

```yaml
CompileFlags:
    Add: [-Wall, -Wextra, -Werror]
```

Answer (score 0):

clangd automatically reads the compilation database from a file called `compile_commands.json`, and reuses compiler flags from there. No need to do anything special in Neovim. For example, a `compile_commands.json` file could look like:

```json
[{
  "directory": ".",
  "file": "test.cpp",
  "arguments": ["g++", "-c", "test.cpp", "-Wall", "-Wextra", "-Werror"]
}]
```

Usually you'll want to generate this file as part of your build process.
CMake can do that out of the box, or you can use `clang -MJ compile_commands.json`.